# What does this mean in this email that I found my husband sending messages like this in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-word, email, microsoft-outlook, code

Email header:

```
X-Gm-Locker: AGMme3PcxTL2JFWN0Vdo0Xv8oI15-23s21Gn1_0qY-R0TsVZqqcXLTtuCL-OtNgO17MIv-dOn8XFhhWLYefojvu6G-XQwFOFstP4D-0OzUr4vDoaoqd3upqbm1nn_d4xHOwUeH9q0z2rTn5Kd2fS17m5WARydrRymRvaCGH5JtaKo4J2D0_5DCO4mw9M7NFhI1etoW8VLBPkwMA1cDP0zBUtTebpWCZY7lY8VwGNq0bepsPcV104
```

Comment: It’s a header indicator that confidential message was sent or received by a Google Suite email

Comment: Ask your husband!

Comment: He claimed it wasn't him. I found out he was sending emails to a women via "confidentially" and I saw one of the emails from "her" and it was in a code like I posted but I had it figured out on a website  but I can't find the site anymore. Husband is now in jail looking at 5years

Comment: It's suggested that you could refer to the below suggestion as DavidPostill mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

#### What does X-Gm-Locker mean in an email header?

Gmail adds this header to the messages that have confidential mode enabled (X-Gm-Locker: ).

> That’s why people are so excited about a new feature in Google’s
> Gmail. It’s called Confidential Mode, and it’s an easy way to make
> email more private.
>
> Confidential Mode lets you add an “expiration date” to emails. Once
> that date arrives, the email is no longer viewable by the recipient.
>
> Messages marked as Confidential can’t be copied, forwarded, printed or
> downloaded <sup>(1)</sup>.
>
> And you can revoke access at any time.

...

> Here’s how to use Confidential Mode. Click on the “Compose” button in
> the upper-left corner. You can write your email as you normally would,
> then click on the small icon at the bottom right that shows a clock in
> front of a lock. Here you can set the expiration for one day, five
> years or any of several durations in between, and also optionally
> choose to require an SMS passcode.
>
> If you do choose the SMS passcode option, you’ll be prompted for the
> recipient’s phone number. The recipient will get the passcode, which
> remains valid only for five minutes.
>
> Best of all, any email sent using Confidential Mode can be revoked at
> any time, regardless of what the expiration date was. Just open the
> email in the “Sent” folder and click “Remove access.” If you’d like to
> make it available again, choose “Renew access.”
>
> Confidential Mode is great, but don’t get lulled into a false sense of
> security. It’s more private than regular email (which isn’t saying
> much). But it’s not as private as other forms of communication. And it
> certainly isn’t secure.

Source: [Watch out for Gmail’s new Confidential Mode | Computerworld](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3272247/watch-out-for-gmail-s-new-confidential-mode.html)

(1) as pointed out by [DrMoishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik) even if it were impossible to take an electronic screen shot, a separate *camera* can

Comment: Good job! Really detailed explanation.